# Unable to create a Solution "Provision cannot be performed because there is no linked CDS instance or the CDS instance version is not supported."

Tags: error, power-automate, powerapp, power-platform, dataverse

I am working on a new Power Platform environment,  and when I tried to create a new Solution >> I got this screen:

[image]

and then I tried to create a new database, I got this error:

[image]

Any advice?

Comment: Are you trying to create it in "default" power platform environment? What roles you have in your Power Platform tenant - Admin/Maker, etc?

Comment: @GaneshSanap yes on the default and i am an admin on the environment

Answer (score 0):

This error message typically means that there is no Common Data Service (CDS) environment linked to the Power Platform environment, or the linked CDS instance is using an unsupported version.

To resolve this issue, you will need to link a CDS instance to your Power Platform environment. To do so, follow these steps:

1. Go to the Power Platform Admin Center and select the environment you are working with.
2. Click on "Settings" from the left-hand menu and select "Linked data sources."
3. Click on "Add data source" and select "Common Data Service."
4. Choose the region and version of the CDS instance you want to link, and enter any required credentials.
5. Follow the prompts to complete the linking process.

Once you have linked a CDS instance to your Power Platform environment, you should be able to create a new Solution without encountering the "Provision cannot be performed because there is no linked CDS instance or the CDS instance version is not supported" error message.